oobabooga-textgen-web-ui how to get authorization to view model list from port 5000 via the ooba's api-key in python
I wish to extract and print out a list of llm models from the oobabooga-text-gen-web-ui in python.
Some context first before i head over to my problem.
For those familiar with what ooba is its essentially a Gradio web UI for Large Language Models.
I downloaded and loaded a few llm models onto this web ui. The web ui uses http://127.0.0.1:7860/ to display the web user interface on port 7860.
But if I enable the openai and api extensions, and also edit the CMD_FLAGS.txt within the ooba folder into something like:
--listen --api --api-key "enter-your-fake-api-key-here" 

the extensions will mimic an Open AI api key by connecting to ooba from a network via port 5000
Here come the problem...
this is my code to view the model list from ooba :
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1"

#Model List
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.get(f'{url}/internal/model/list',
                        headers=headers,
                        verify=False)
print(response.json())

the output should look something like this:
{'model_names': ['L3-8B-Stheno-v3.2', 'L3-8B-Stheno-v3.2_exl2_8h_8bpw', 'L3-8B-Stheno-v3.2_q8_0.gguf', 'MixTAO-7Bx2-MoE-v8.1_q8_0.gguf']}

but instead i got this:
{'detail': 'Unauthorized'}

After some fiddling around I found that if I leave CMD_FLAGS.txt blank the code works as intended and i get the model lists but i dont have access to an API key since its not enable on ooba.
if I do enable it with CMD_FLAGS.txt and typing:
--listen --api --api-key "enter-your-fake-api-key-here" 

I'll have access to the openai api key but the code to extract the model list will return as :
{'detail': 'Unauthorized'}
I need the api key enabled from ooba cuz i plan to use the openai.client feature for model interactions.
How do I keep the configuration that enables the fake open ai api key but also allows me to extract the model list?

1 day later... Found the answer.
Turns out if i want the api key to be enabled while also being able to view the model list from ooba via the api, I need to add an 'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}' in the header.
The code should look something like this:
import requests

api_key = "enter-your-fake-api-key-here"
url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1"

#Model List
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}"
}

response = requests.get(f'{url}/internal/model/list',
                        headers=headers,
                        verify=False)
print(response.json())

